# Some url showing as " Bad Request (Invalid URL) " on browserfield

Tags: blackberry

I've display a webpage using browserfield. It showing all webpage successfully.

But when i pass the this url http://mobile.idaholottery.com/#page-last5pb

The web page hasn't display. Its shows "Bad Request URL" but if i try to open on brower, its loading.

My code is,

```java
BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();
String userAgent = "BlackBerry" + DeviceInfo.getDeviceName() + "/" + 
           DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion() +" Profile/" + 
           System.getProperty("microedition.profiles") +" Configuration/" + 
           System.getProperty( "microedition.configuration") + " VendorID/" + 
           Branding.getVendorId();
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.USER_AGENT, userAgent);
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ALLOW_CS_XHR, Boolean.TRUE);
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ENABLE_GEARS, Boolean.TRUE);
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE, BrowserFiedConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);    
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ENABLE_COOKIES,Boolean.TRUE);
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.USER_SCALABLE, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Why isn't open on browserfield and How to show the url in bb browserfield, any setting need to add?